# 2 buttons on right side of navBar in ionic2

Tags: html, ionic2

Is it possible to put 2 buttons on right side of navigation bar in ionic2?

This code only displays search button on right side.

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title>Items</ion-title>
  <ion-buttons end>
    <button (click)="searchTapped($event)">
      <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button (click)="createTapped($event)">
      <ion-icon name="ion-plus-round"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your code places two buttons on the right side of the navbar

Comment: Thank you. But the above code displays only search button.

Comment: review the name of the icons, the code is right, see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/CZ6GnJkCHdU4doADqEx4?p=preview